# Checking with Cloud Function if a database node exists in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a onUpdate Cloud Function and I need to check if a database node exists.

For my the ideal way to do it would be:

```
exports.watchTeamMemberUpdates = functions.database
  .ref('/teams/{teamName}')
  .onUpdate((change) => {
     if (!change.before.exists()) {
       console.log('exists error');
       return null;
     }
});
```

But it requires a snapshot and i'm giving it a promise.

Is it possible to check if the file exists with the promise in any way?

Also is there a better way to make snapshots other than .once.then?

Comment: What do you mean by "Also is there a better way to make snapshots other than .once.then?"? You may ask another SO question on this point, instead of combining two questions in one SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I make the assumption that by writing "I need to check if a **file** exists" you mean checking if a **database node** exists (i.e. the team member saved under team name).* I've taken the liberty to modify your question title and content accordingly.

---

Note that if you want to detect if the team member didn't exist with an `onUpdate()` trigger, **you will not succeed**, because this Cloud Function **will only be triggered if the node existed before**, since we watch for updates (not for creation).

So you should probably use an `onWrite()` trigger. Below is the code for the two types of trigger. I would suggest you try several writes and updates in your database (after having deployed theses two functions, of course) and look what is printed to the Cloud Function log.

```
exports.watchTeamMemberUpdates = functions.database
  .ref('/teams/{teamName}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    if (!change.before.exists()) {
      console.log('watchTeamMemberUpdates: exists error');
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log('watchTeamMemberUpdates: Team member exists');
      return null;
    }
  });

exports.watchTeamMemberWrites = functions.database
  .ref('/teams/{teamName}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (!change.before.exists()) {
      console.log('watchTeamMemberWrites: exists error');
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log('watchTeamMemberWrites: Team member exists');
      return null;
    }
  });
```

PS: Note that the handler to be passed to the `onUpdate(handler)` method is a function with two arguments, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate. However the second is optional. This is the same with the `onWrite(handler)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the onWrite suggestion but a question about the 2 arguments, if we're not using one of the arguments (for example in another onUpdate function i don't use context) isn't it cleaner to just remove the context or do you still need to write it down?